# basic question on integration

Tags: calculus, integration

is 
$$
\int(A + B) \cdot \,dl = \int A \cdot \,dl+ \int B \cdot \,dl
$$
or in  others words is integral of sum of two vectors equal to sum of integral of the two vectors

Comment: note that (anywhere on mathSE) if you right-click an expression, then click "show mathjax" on the drop-down menu you can see the way the mathjax is written

Comment: thank you i am new to stack exchange

Comment: @rjmessibarca A,B are vectors ? What do you mean by vector ?

Comment: You should avoid situations like $+\infty = -\infty +\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$X=\int\Big(\dfrac{dX}{dl}\Big) \cdot \,dl   $$
$$Y=\int\Big(\dfrac{dY}{dl}\Big) \cdot \,dl$$
$$X+Y=\int\Big(\dfrac{d(X+Y)}{dl}\Big) \cdot \,dl$$
$$\implies \int \Big(\dfrac{dX}{dl}\Big) \cdot \,dl+\int\Big(\dfrac{dY}{dl}\Big) \cdot \,dl=\int\Big(\dfrac{d(X+Y)}{dl}\Big) \cdot \,dl$$

Now put $$\Big(\dfrac{dX}{dl}\Big)=A$$$$\Big(\dfrac{dY}{dl}\Big)=B$$

Fnally 
$$
\int(A + B) \cdot \,dl = \int A \cdot \,dl+ \int B \cdot \,dl
$$

Answer (score 0):

Think of the situation in this manner

work done due to two forces is equal to the work done due to individual ones.

let F1 be the first force and F2 be the second force than the work done by the two forces on a particle to move it in a line S is given by (F1.S + F2.S)  (. indicates dot product) which is equal to (F1+F2).S

Hope this helped.